# Evaluate a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Evaluate: $$\int_{0}^{1} x^2\sqrt{(kx^2-1)(kx^2-1+t)}\, dx$$

where k and t are constants.

Can you help me?

Comment: This looks like a job for integration under the integral sign.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried $$kx^2-1=z$$ but nothing...what do you suggest? Have you tried to solve it on your own?

Comment: Instead of trying $kx^2-1=z$ try $z^2$

Comment: Have you put a space between x and k?

Comment: I have solved the indefinite integral using mathematica: http://i.imgur.com/lHBkdmC.png   input: `Integrate[x^2*Sqrt[(k x^2 - 1) (k x^2 - 1 + t)], x]`

Comment: This is the final result http://i.imgur.com/eyB0hhE.png

Comment: @user154564 The result posted is fairly simple as far as elliptic integrals go. Have you encountered elliptic integrals before?